pac4j returns an error refreshing an expired token
Checked with pac4j-5.7.7 and pac4j-6.0.6 and using Keycloak and AWS Cognito as OpenId provider, always reproducible in all the 4 cases.
When I configure the client to use the nonce in the token I can get the first token without any problem. However, once the token expires and it's got to be refreshed, I get an error
com.nimbusds.jose.proc.BadJOSEException: Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found
 at PluginClassLoader for oic-auth//com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:357)
 at PluginClassLoader for oic-auth//com.nimbusds.openid.connect.sdk.validators.IDTokenValidator.validate(IDTokenValidator.java:321)
 at PluginClassLoader for oic-auth//com.nimbusds.openid.connect.sdk.validators.IDTokenValidator.validate(IDTokenValidator.java:254)
 at PluginClassLoader for oic-auth//org.pac4j.oidc.profile.creator.TokenValidator.validate(TokenValidator.java:108)
 at PluginClassLoader for oic-auth//org.pac4j.oidc.profile.creator.OidcProfileCreator.create(OidcProfileCreator.java:109)
Caused: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException
 at PluginClassLoader for oic-auth//org.pac4j.oidc.profile.creator.OidcProfileCreator.create(OidcProfileCreator.java:153)
 at PluginClassLoader for oic-auth//org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.retrieveUserProfile(BaseClient.java:126)
 at PluginClassLoader for oic-auth//org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.getUserProfile(BaseClient.java:105)
 at PluginClassLoader for oic-auth//org.pac4j.oidc.client.OidcClient.renewUserProfile(OidcClient.java:69)

My understanding from the OpenId specification the refresh token should not have a nonce Claim, even when the ID Token issued at the time of the original authentication contained nonce. If it is present, its value must be the same as in the ID Token issued at the time of the original authentication.
If I set the OicdConfiguration object with setUseNonce(false), the error does not happen, as if the validator is expecting always the nonce Claim in the refresh token. However, if I set the OicdConfiguration object with setUseNonce(true) I cannot refresh the token, what seems to go against the OpenId specification.

The nonce is in the ID token, not in the refresh token.
As it fails on the ID token validation, I guess an ID token is returned upon the Successful Refresh Response, right?
Does this ID token contains a nonce?

No, it doesn't. When authenticating the first time, the ID token contains the nonce claim as expected. When the token expires and have to refresh, the TokenValidator.validate method is receiving an expected nonce that is the same as the first ID token. However, the ID token at that moment doesn't contain the nonce. This is the behaviour using Keycloak and AWS Cognito.

OK. On the successful refresh response, you get an ID token without the claims token, which is totally compliant with the spec. Seeing the source code of the Nimbus lib used by pac4j, it should work. Strange! Can you turn on DEBUG logs on org.pac4j.oidc.profile.creator.TokenValidator and see the detailed exception? Thx

please find it in https://github.com/fcojfernandez/public/blob/main/TokenValidator.log @jleleu

Indeed, you are right about the problem: Trying IDToken validator: com.nimbusds.openid.connect.sdk.validators.IDTokenValidator@17c0bc23 nov 06, 2024 7:02:05 P. M. DETALLADO org.pac4j.oidc.profile.creator.TokenValidator validate Missing JWT nonce (nonce) claim com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.BadJWTException: Missing JWT nonce (nonce) claim  at PluginClassLoader for oic-auth//com.nimbusds.openid.connect.sdk.validators.BadJWTExceptions.<clinit>(BadJWTExceptions.java:70)

So there is a bug in pac4j: I guess we should add a renew boolean when calling the getUserProfile method to pass it to the profile creator and not use the nonce in that case. Would you mind submitting a PR? Thanks

Yes, happy to submit the PR, but I cannot commit a date for that PR
